# is the use of appendTail(StringBuffer sb)?

Tags: java, append

I found a problem in this amazing tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html).

First, this is the code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class RegexDemo {

private static String REGEX = "a*b";
private static String INPUT = "aabfooaabfooabfoob";
private static String REPLACE = "-";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT); // get a matcher object
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while(m.find()){
        m.appendReplacement(sb,REPLACE);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
}
```

The output: -foo-foo-foo-

After seeing the documentation about the appendTail() method:

> Implements a terminal append-and-replace step.
>
> This method reads characters from the input sequence, starting at the append position, and appends them to the given string buffer. It is intended to be invoked after one or more invocations of the appendReplacement method in order to copy the remainder of the input sequence.

I got the same output when i remove `m.appendTail(sb);`

I can not understand why calling this method. I suppose it is called implicitly. Isn't it?

Comment: End your input string with another character then `b`, then you see the difference

Comment: Yes. i see, thanks Ferrybig :)